# In Soylent Green, is humanity doomed?

Tags: soylent-green

Planet earth in this movie is **severely** overpopulated, and there doesn’t seem to be much of nature left.

Are we being left, at the end of the film, with the impression that humanity is *entirely* doomed?

Comment: Their oceans are dead. It's game over.

Comment: "The meat is all around us. Tasty meat-Fingers and toes and noses... "

Comment: @DoscoJones - The screenplay would suggest that the oceans are *dying*, not dead

Comment: The funny thing is that the population of the "severely overpopulated" United States of the original Harrison novel, and the population of the world at large, is *lower* than the actual population of both today.  Harrison made some classic Ehrlich errors in his projections.

Comment: As commented above by Dosco Jones, without oceans, we are screwed. I believe that simplistically they saw the oceans dying meaning solely that a major source of food was becoming unavailable; but the emergent problem with dying oceans is that the atmosphere would be affected -- the ocean plays a major role in producing oxygen from carbon dioxide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the film's [original screenplay](https://www.scriptslug.com/script/soylent-green-1973), humanity isn't *necessarily* doomed, but the corruption of the mega-corporations and the  intransigence of the Council of Nations (a fictional stand-in for the UN) means that humanity will likely *continue* down a path that leads to its extinction.

> ANGLE TO SOL [He speaks through tears with a broken voice]
>
> **SOL:** *It’s horrible.*
>
> **THE LEADER:** *You must accept it.*
>
> **SOL:** [studying a sheaf of papers] *I see the words. I can't believe them.*
>
> **LEADER:** *Believe. The evidence is overwhelming. Simonson was a member of the Board. He learned these facts and they shook his sanity.
> The Corporation knew that he had become unreliable, feared that he
> might talk, and so eliminated him. In a sense he was killed by the
> horror of what he knew.*
>
> **#1:** ***The real tragedy is there is still time. Even now.***
>
> **LEADER:** ***The sea can be revitalized. We can enforce birth control.***
>
> **SOL** [flashing papers in his hand] *Then why are they doing this?*
>
> **LEADER:** *Because it’s easier. I think expedient is the word. Convenient...practical. What we need is proof of what they're doing
> before we can bring it to the Council of Nations.*
>
> [Sol listens in numbed disbelief to what follows. He's heard this song
> before. As the conversation continues in b.g., he slowly starts to
> leave the room, hands papers back to Leader.
>
> **#1:** *If only they'd listen. If only we could break down this insane insistence that regulating the size of a family is
> irreligious... The Council of Nations still considers it Immoral.*
>
> **SOL:** *Dear God.*
>
> **LEADER:** *What God, Mr. Roth. Where will we find Him?*
>
> **SOL:** [turning away, mumbling to himself] *Perhaps at Home — yes, at Home* [he starts to exit]
>
> **#2:** *Klyner's theory -- manipulate the genes! The girl babies, the breeders, they’re the problem. Fix it so that just one out of every
> thousand births is female and you've eliminated the incubator.*
>
> **LEADER:** *And you’ve grown a civilization of homosexuals! No, we must look elsewhere for the answer.*

Comment: “And you’ve grown a civilization of homosexuals! No” — did they not have _Queer Eye_ in that universe?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite The timeline deviated much earlier than that x)